# ProgressIndicator display loading while my report execute using java fx

Tags: java, javafx, jasper-reports

I have a report and `ProgressIndicator` and button

I'm writing a program in javafx where different report a. The report values are based on data collected from a database. Since I have to first collect the data from the database and then do som further calculations in the code some of the report take some time to load. I would like a progress indicator to show the progress of the report loading. Before the chart is shown the user selects what kind of chart he/she wants and then clicks a 'Go' button to view the chart.

When the user clicks the 'Go' button the report starts loading and I would like the progress indicator to show the loading progress in percent. The problem is that as soon as the report starts loading the progress indicator freezes. All changes that I try to do to the progress bar (and the text below it) will not be done until the entire report is fully loaded, which kind of ruins the whole purpose of the progress indicator.

Is there any way to make the progress indicator change WHILE the report is loading?

Thanks!

This is my code:

```
@FXML
private ProgressIndicator A;

@FXML
public
void report(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    try {
        Connection con = dbcontt.getconction();
        JasperReport js;
        js = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("bin/report/A4.jrxml");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(js, null, con);
        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
        jv.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error.writeExption(e);
        error.Exption(e);
    }
```

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking, but I'll take a guess. You want the `ProgressIndicator` to show the progress of your report being run? If so, where is the code you have tried to do that?

Comment: Consider optimizing the report query and any under-performing Java code so that a progress indicator is not required. In my experience, even complex reports once optimized only take half a second to run. If the reports take a rather long time to run, a batch system that runs nightly (hourly?) could be a viable alternative -- get machines to pre-compute reports in their spare time, rather than burdening humans with the wait.